# How to fire a Text Changed event a Template Column in Data Grid

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

Iam new to Silveligt and Data Grid. Iam trying to fire a Text Changed event for a Template Column in Data Grid . But its not working. Niether Grid events like these are firing.

```
BeginningEdit="dataGrid1_BeginningEdit" 
TextInputStart="dataGrid1_TextInputStart"
TextInputUpdate="dataGrid1_TextInputUpdate" PreparingCellForEdit="dataGrid1_PreparingCellForEdit"
```

Am I missing some thing ? Iam binding data from a list.

This is the xaml

```
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,96,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" BeginningEdit="dataGrid1_BeginningEdit"  TextInputStart="dataGrid1_TextInputStart" TextInputUpdate="dataGrid1_TextInputUpdate" PreparingCellForEdit="dataGrid1_PreparingCellForEdit" LoadingRow="dataGrid1_LoadingRow">


<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Test" Width="Auto"   >
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Urgency}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Column2" Width="Auto" >
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox />
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>


</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Are you receiving an exception??

Comment: Thanks Glenn. No. The breakpoint never hits inside the event handler

Comment: Have you tried <TextBox Text="{Binding Urgency}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" /> ?

Answer (score 1):

Right click your silverlight datagrid Goto ->Properties and then click the TextBox that you want to add the selection changed event, In the properties tool bar you cant find the text changed event.

[image]

Then it will automatically generate an event for text changed.

```
  private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan .. Actually I had tried that..But missed to update the xaml that I posted. But that is not working either. Break point is not hit for that event too.

Comment: You need to remove the other events for that textbox to get it work!

Comment: Thanks..But I haven't attached any other event..But only the TextChanged event

Comment: You have mentioned that you have events for the grid, better remove those and check

Answer (score 1):

`CellTemplate` for `DataGrid` is just a display template. `CellEditingTemplate` would actually behave according to your requirement.

The code below will fire the `textchange` event.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Test" Width="Auto">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Urgency}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Urgency, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about changing your binding to :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Urgency, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

and then handle the OnPropertyChanged event fired by Urgency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a property that you bind (or manually code) to handle the DataGrid's "SelectedItem", and then attach to the "PropertyChanged" event?
Then you can "sniff" for changes to any of the selected item and do any action you like.

Another tip is to also define the "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" in any bindings on TextBoxes.
This means that the data binding change is done when the text is changed apposed to when the TextBox lose focus (as default).